# Flutter - Using PathUrlStrategy on Azure Static Web App

Tags: flutter, azure, azure-static-web-app

I have a flutter web app that runs fine locally, however, when uploaded to the Azure infrastructure (via [Azure Static Web Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/products/app-service/static/#features)) I run into problems using the `PathUrlStrategy` option - when the url is entered manually there's a 404 returned.  From [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-your-web-server) it states that there's some server config to do (but isn't clear about what).

After a bit of digging, I've found a [reference](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/81910#issuecomment-833651794) to a .htaccess file (problem seems to be similar - treating the path as a subdirectory) but I'm not sure how to apply it to the static web app config?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - got there in the end!

Using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/configuration), specifically this bit:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

I've added a `staticwebapp.config.json` file to the root of the flutter app.  This didn't seem to be utilised until also adding this line to `pubspec.yaml`

```
  assets:
    - staticwebapp.config.json
```